# DataError value too long for type character varying(16) in django social_auth

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

Im trying to setup django socail auth. I have configured everything according to docs and its working at the point where I can authenticate with google from my django app. But after authentication from google, when the request comes back to my app I'm getting the following error:

```
DataError at /auth/complete/google-oauth2/
value too long for type character varying(16)
```

I looked up on google and found that this is caused by storing a value whose length is greater than 16 in a variable of length 16 (If I'm not wrong).

But I cannot figure out which variable it is that is causing this error.

I have looked at social_auth models.py and no variable has length of 16.

Have any of you guys had a similar problem?

TIA

Comment: Do you have a custom user model? Any other model in your project that could have a field with that length? Also, which DB are you using?

Comment: Yes I have a custom user model. I'm using posgtresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up in `pgAdmin` and the field that was causing this problem was `uid` of `UserSocialAuth` model.

It had a length of 16, I changed it to 255 and it solved the problem.

Comment: There's a setting for that ``SOCIAL_AUTH_UID_LENGTH``, but still you need a migration to make the change.

Comment: looks like UUID not UID which has the 16 bit chars?